# Nginx block POST for certain countries

Tags: security, nginx, geoip

I have a reverse proxy nginx to tomcat.

My goal is to ban total access to certain countries and ban POST for all countries except one.

Total access ban for certain countries can be achieved via iptables at kernel level. That is a easy task.

My dilemma is how I ban only POST from all countries except one. Rest of them can see the website (GET) but I don't want them to create accounts, or post data.

I could filter by listing all forms that use post, but are too many.

Is any way to filter with nginx only post?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geo $ip_country {
  ranges;
  default zz;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/ip_country.conf;
}

set $method_country $request_method$ip_country;
if ($method_country ~ "POST(?!au)") {
    return 405;
}
```

ip_country.conf format like:

```
0.0.0.0-0.255.255.255 eu;
1.0.0.0-1.0.0.255     au;
1.0.1.0-1.0.3.255     cn;
1.0.4.0-1.0.7.255     au;
1.0.8.0-1.0.15.255    cn;
1.0.16.0-1.0.31.255   jp;
1.0.32.0-1.0.63.255   cn;
1.0.64.0-1.0.127.255  jp;
1.0.128.0-1.0.255.255 th;
1.1.0.0-1.1.0.255     cn;
...
```

and you could use `$ip_country` value inside your scripts with:

```
fastcgi_param IP_COUNTRY $ip_country;
```

Comment: Tnx! I will implement it tonight! Cheers for that

Comment: For some reason nginx didn't liked your if clause. I replaced with something really ugly:
    #GEO
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $test P;
    }

    if ($ip_country != au) {
        set $test "${test}C";
    }

    if ($test = PC) {
        return 405;
    }

Comment: Sry, i have corrected this with `set $method_country $request_method$ip_country;`

Comment: How would the `if` line look if the country name had more than one possible valid value and/or had spaces in the valid value(s)?

Comment: Answering my own question: `if ($method_country ~ "POST(?!(ca|us|value with spaces))") {`